# com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "registrationDate"

Tags: java, class, data-binding, jackson

I need to correctly invoke a rest api but I am getting an error when executing my service below I show the LOG:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "registrationDate" (class pe.com.claro.api.consultadeuda.bean.consultarclientes.response.BodyCC), not marked as ignorable (36 known properties: "currencyRef", "actualDue", "name", "accountTypeRef", "secondaryRefCode", "activeSegment", "writeOff", "oldestPastDueDate", "actualPastDue", "collectibleDue", "id", "services", "lastModificationDate" [truncated]])
 at [Source: weblogic.net.http.KeepAliveStream@1f2182b9; line: 1, column: 120]
```

THE RESPONSE OF THE REST API IS AS FOLLOWS, I HAVE OMITTED PLACING SOME OBJECTS SO AS NOT TO MAKE THE COMMENT SO LONG, I HAVE PLACED THE SERVICE OBJECT BECAUSE THERE IS THE registrationDate FIELD THAT IS CAUSING ME PROBLEMS:

```
[
    {
        "id": "2511",
        "href": null,
        "baseType": null,
        "type": null,
        "name": "BSCS-84253625",
        "debtorReference": {
            "id": "1987",
            "href": null,
            "baseType": null,
            "type": null,
            "name": "ALONSO REYNA DIAZ ALONSO REYNA DIAZ"
        }
        "services": [
            {
                "id": "2427",
                "href": null,
                "baseType": null,
                "type": null,
                "name": "Mobile Subscription",
                "referenceNumber": "CO_ID_00012022040855-1-SP2022040855",
                "productLine": "S",
                "serialNumber": "985212361",
                "registrationDate": "2022-04-08T17:29:43+02:00",
                "activationDate": "2021-11-30T23:00:00+01:00",
                "deactivationDate": null,
                "contractNumber": "12022040855",
                "serviceExternalCode": "SP2022040855",
                "subType": "001"
            }
        ],
        "activeSegment": null,
        "activeScoring": null
    }
]
```

THIS IS MY CLASS ConsultClientesResponseCCli , HERE I CREATED A LIST TO SHOW THE RESPONSE OF THE API REST.

```
 import lombok.Getter;
    import lombok.Setter;
    import java.util.List;
    @Getter
    @Setter
    public class ConsultarClientesResponseCCli{
      private List<BodyCC> body;
    }
```

The BodyCC class: HERE ARE ALL FIELDS OF THE RESPONSE OF THE API REST TO WHICH I CONSUME.

```
public class BodyCC {
    @JsonProperty("id")
    private String id;
    @JsonProperty("href")
    private Object href;
    @JsonProperty("baseType")
    private Object baseType;
    @JsonProperty("type")
    private Object type;
    @JsonProperty("name")
    private String name;
    @JsonProperty("debtorReference")
    private DebtorReference debtorReference;
    @JsonProperty("accountSrvRef")
    private Object accountSrvRef;
    @JsonProperty("accountLedgerRef")
    private AccountLedgerRef accountLedgerRef;
    @JsonProperty("accountTypeRef")
    private AccountTypeRef accountTypeRef;
    @JsonProperty("creationDate")
    private String creationDate;
    @JsonProperty("lastModificationDate")
    private Object lastModificationDate;
    @JsonProperty("oldestPastDueDate")
    private Object oldestPastDueDate;
    @JsonProperty("accountnumber")
    private String accountnumber;
    @JsonProperty("referenceNumber")
    private String referenceNumber;
    @JsonProperty("aging")
    private Integer aging;
    @JsonProperty("status")
    private Status status;
    @JsonProperty("actualDue")
    private ActualDue actualDue;
    @JsonProperty("actualPastDue")
    private ActualPastDue actualPastDue;
    @JsonProperty("collectibleDue")
    private Object collectibleDue;
    @JsonProperty("collectiblePastDue")
    private Object collectiblePastDue;
    @JsonProperty("securitized")
    private Securitized securitized;
    @JsonProperty("unbilled")
    private Unbilled unbilled;
    @JsonProperty("writeOff")
    private WriteOff writeOff;
    @JsonProperty("arranged")
    private Arranged arranged;
    @JsonProperty("unexpired")
    private Unexpired unexpired;
    @JsonProperty("provider")
    private Provider provider;
    @JsonProperty("parentAccount")
    private Object parentAccount;
    @JsonProperty("additionalData1")
    private Object additionalData1;
    @JsonProperty("additionalData2")
    private Object additionalData2;
    @JsonProperty("additionalData3")
    private Object additionalData3;
    @JsonProperty("secondaryRefCode")
    private Object secondaryRefCode;
    @JsonProperty("paymentResponsibles")
    private List<PaymentResponsible> paymentResponsibles = null;
    @JsonProperty("currencyRef")
    private CurrencyRef currencyRef;
    @JsonProperty("services")
    private List<Service> services = null;
    @JsonProperty("activeSegment")
    private Object activeSegment;
    @JsonProperty("activeScoring")
    private Object activeScoring;
}
```

my rest api invocation class, which contains the implementation to call rest.

```
@Component
public class ConsultarClientesImpl implements ConsultarClientes {
  private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ConsultarClientesImpl.class);
  @Autowired
  private PropiedadesExternas prop;
  @Override
  public ConsultarClientesResponseCCli consultarClientes(String msgx, String token, String identificationType,
      String identificationValue) throws WSException {

    long tiempoInicio = System.currentTimeMillis();
    String url = prop.wsConsultarClientesURL;
    String contentType = prop.wsConsultarClientesContentType;
    String metodo = prop.wsConsultarClientesMetodo;
    WebResource webResource = null;
    ConsultarClientesResponseCCli response = new ConsultarClientesResponseCCli();
    try {
      Client client = Client.create();
      client.setConnectTimeout(prop.wsConsultarClientesTiempoConexion);
      client.setReadTimeout(prop.wsConsultarClientesTiempoEjecucion);
      webResource = client.resource(url).queryParam("identificationType", identificationType)
          .queryParam("identificationValue", identificationValue);
      logger.info(Constantes.CHAR_CORCHETE_IZQUIERDO + msgx + Constantes.CHAR_CORCHETE_DERECHO + Constantes.URL+ webResource.getURI());

       List<BodyCC> body = webResource.accept("application/json").header("content-type", contentType).header("Authorization", "Bearer " + token).get(new GenericType<List<BodyCC>>(){});
     response.setBody(body);
     logger.info(Constantes.CHAR_CORCHETE_IZQUIERDO + msgx + Constantes.CHAR_CORCHETE_DERECHO + Constantes.PARAM_SALIDA
        + ClaroUtil.printPrettyJSONString(response));

    } catch (Exception e) {
      logger.error(Constantes.ERROR + e.getMessage(), e);
      capturarError(e, webResource);

    } finally {
      logger.info(Constantes.CHAR_CORCHETE_IZQUIERDO + msgx + Constantes.CHAR_CORCHETE_DERECHO
          + " Tiempo total de proceso(ms): " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - tiempoInicio));
      logger.info(
          Constantes.CHAR_CORCHETE_IZQUIERDO + msgx + Constantes.CHAR_CORCHETE_DERECHO + " [FIN de metodo: " + metodo);
    }
    return response;
  }
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to stack overflow.  This is just a guess, but perhaps the registrationDate field is actually null or not present in the returned json?  The error message states "not marked as ignorable" meaning, if the value is not there, throw an exception.  I'm betting that if you changed your Service's registrationDate attribute to ignorable, things might start working better.  Just a guess though.